Opencv coordinate transformation: Rotate a rotated coordinate system by one of its new (rotated) axes
For my thesis I am doing a computer vision project. Part of this is a lot of coordinate transformations which i struggle with at the moment. I just cannot rotate my coordinate system by an arbitrary axis.
I start with 3D coordinates of an object. Given that I configured the camera and know the camera matrix and distort coefficients I can project that point back to a 2D image.
Now I want to obtain the euler angles of a coordinate system so that the Z-Axis of the coordinate system points directly towards the optical center (the camera).
For completeness sake here are the helper functions from my code. For my main problem please skip towards the next Textblock.
def coordinate_system_to_image(image, custom_rotation, custom_translation):
    origin_3d = np.array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)])
    start_point_coord, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(origin_3d,custom_rotation,custom_translation,mtx,dist,)

    point0 = (int(start_point_coord[0][0][0]), int(start_point_coord[0][0][1]))
    pointx_3d = np.add(origin_3d, np.array([(2.5, 0.0, 0.0)]))
    end_point_x, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(pointx_3d,custom_rotation,custom_translation,mtx,dist,)
    pointx = (int(end_point_x[0][0][0]), int(end_point_x[0][0][1]))

    pointy_3d = np.add(origin_3d, np.array([(0.0, 2.5, 0.0)]))
    end_point_y, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(pointy_3d,custom_rotation,custom_translation,mtx,dist,)
    pointy = (int(end_point_y[0][0][0]), int(end_point_y[0][0][1]))

    pointz_3d = np.add(origin_3d, np.array([(0, 0.0, 2.5)]))
    end_point_z, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(pointz_3d,custom_rotation,custom_translation,mtx,dist,)
    pointz = (int(end_point_z[0][0][0]), int(end_point_z[0][0][1]))

    cv2.line(image, point0, pointx, (255, 0, 0), 5)
    cv2.line(image, point0, pointy, (0, 255, 0), 5)
    cv2.line(image, point0, pointz, (0, 0, 255), 5)

    cv2.circle(image, (int(start_point_coord[0][0][0]), int(start_point_coord[0][0][1])), 10, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    return image

def coords_rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle(axis,angle):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle
    ux = axis[0]
    uy = axis[1]
    uz = axis[2]

    length = ux**2 + uy**2 + uz**2
    if(length != 1.0):
        print("Length of axis != 1")
        return False

    Mx11 = ux*ux*(1-np.cos(angle)) + np.cos(angle)
    Mx12 = ux*uy*(1-np.cos(angle)) - uz*np.sin(angle)
    Mx13 = ux*uz*(1-np.cos(angle)) + uy*np.sin(angle)
    Mx21 = ux*uy*(1-np.cos(angle)) + uz*np.sin(angle)
    Mx22 = uy*uy*(1-np.cos(angle)) + np.cos(angle)
    Mx23 = uy*uz*(1-np.cos(angle)) - ux*np.sin(angle)
    Mx31 = ux*uz*(1-np.cos(angle)) - uy*np.sin(angle)
    Mx32 = uy*uz*(1-np.cos(angle)) + ux*np.sin(angle)
    Mx33 = uz*uz*(1-np.cos(angle)) + np.cos(angle)
    Mx = np.array([[Mx11, Mx12, Mx13], [Mx21, Mx22, Mx23], [Mx31, Mx32, Mx33]])
    return Mx

def coords_rotation_matrix_to_euler(rotation_matrix):
    r11 = rotation_matrix[0][0]
    r21 = rotation_matrix[1][0]
    r31 = rotation_matrix[2][0]
    r32 = rotation_matrix[2][1]
    r33 = rotation_matrix[2][2]

    degy_reverse1 = -1*np.arcsin(r31)
    degy_reverse2 = np.pi - degy_reverse1

    degx_reverse1 = np.arctan2(r32/np.cos(degy_reverse1), r33/np.cos(degy_reverse1))
    degx_reverse2 = np.arctan2(r32/np.cos(degy_reverse2), r33/np.cos(degy_reverse2))

    degz_reverse1 = np.arctan2(r21/np.cos(degy_reverse1), r11/np.cos(degy_reverse1))
    degz_reverse2 = np.arctan2(r21/np.cos(degy_reverse2), r11/np.cos(degy_reverse2))
    print(f"Extracted Eulers 2: X:({degx_reverse1},{degx_reverse2}) Y:({degy_reverse1},{degy_reverse2}) Z:({degz_reverse1},{degz_reverse2})")
    return degx_reverse1, degy_reverse1, degz_reverse1

The first part of the system works well. I can set 3D coordinates, determine the x- and y-angles and print an according coordinate system that has its z-axis towards the camera as expected (z-axis "disappears" in the plot).
demo = np.zeros((2988, 5312, 3))
demo = np.uint8(demo)

pos3dx_wchess = 5.0
pos3dy_wchess = -3
pos3dz_wchess = 30
degx_camera3d = np.arctan(pos3dy_wchess/pos3dz_wchess)
degy_camera3d = -1*np.arctan(pos3dx_wchess/pos3dz_wchess)
degz_camera3d = 0

connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation = np.array([[-1*degx_camera3d, -1*degy_camera3d, -1*degz_camera3d]])
print(connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation)
custom_translation = np.array([[pos3dx_wchess, pos3dy_wchess, pos3dz_wchess]])

demo = coordinate_system_to_image(demo, custom_rotation=connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation, custom_translation=custom_translation)

M_rot = coords_euler_to_rotation_matrix(connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation[0][0],connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation[0][1],connector_pointing_to_camera_orientation[0][2])
print("Test retreive angles:",coords_rotation_matrix_to_euler(M_rot))


[[0.09966865 0.16514868 0.        ]]
Test retreive angles: (0.09966865249116204, 0.1651486774146268, 0.0)
The test print also shows, that the angle conversion from the rotation matrix works.
Now I want to rotate that coordinate system around its new z-axis. This z-axis of course does no longer align with the camera z-axis because it was rotated by the previous rotation.
So I first obtain the new rotation axis, then create the according rotation matrix for a rotation of 45 degrees, combine the two rotation matrices, get the euler angles from the combined rotation matrix and plot the new rotated coordinate system.
world_point_z_axis = np.array([0,0,1])
second_axis = np.matmul(M_rot, world_point_z_axis)  # equals M_rot @ world_point_z_axis

second_matrix = coords_rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle(second_axis,45*np.pi/180)

combined = second_matrix @ M_rot #np.matmul(second_matrix, M_rot)

new_eulerx, new_eulery, new_eulerz = coords_rotation_matrix_to_euler(combined)
new_rotation = np.array([new_eulerx, new_eulery, new_eulerz])

print(img_shape)

demo2 = coordinate_system_to_image(demo2, custom_rotation=new_rotation, custom_translation=custom_translation)

This does not work for some reason. In the new plot the X and Y axes look somewhat alright but it seems that the rotation was not executed around the rotated z-axis from the first rotation because now this axis is visible again. It seems more like the rotation was done around the cameras z-axis rather than the rotated one.

Is there a mistake in my pipeline? Why is the second rotation not executed around the seperately produced axis?
Best regards,
Felix

use matrix multiplication to compose transformations (which are matrices, 4x4 when in 3D space). -- use cv.Rodrigues to generate a 3x3 rotation matrix from an axis and angle (|v| = angle), also to transform back. you should have two utility functions, one each, for those two operations. -- give up on euler angles. define every rotation as an explicit axis and angle. if you need euler angles out of a rotation matrix, you can hide that in one utility function -- remove all that indexing. move that into utility functions, if you need to at all. -- [edit] your question to revise it.

use destructuring bind to reduce indexing: (x, y, z) = something, [[m11, m12, m13], [m21, m22, m23]] = something and so on -- oh and write tests for everything. tests can be trivial. just a bunch of assert statements. test various ideal inputs and outputs. have enough test cases that you can be reasonably sure the function doesn't accidentally return the expected value. e.g. for a function making rotation matrices, send the basis vectors (or any three orthogonal ones of weird length, not just unit length) into the function and check that they're mapped to where they're supposed to be.
